# xgboost predict wrong result when creating dmatrix from numpy array

Tags: pandas, numpy, xgboost

I have a trained XGBoost model and the model predict well when I create xgboost dmatrix from pandas dataframe during test. But when I create xgboost dmatrix from numpy array, the model always predict wrong result.

**Load data and model**

```
import xgboost as xgb
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# load data
img_obj = Image.open('bob_digit/5/aaaa0_x0_y2.bmp')
data_list = list((255 - np.array(img_obj)).reshape(-1))

# load bst model
bst_model = xgb.Booster({'bthread': 2})
bst_model.load_model('bob_digit/bob_digit_classification.model')
```

**Predict right, create dmatrix from dataframe**

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
col_names = ['f%d' % i for i in range(680)]
df = df.append(pd.Series(data=data_list, index=col_names), ignore_index=True)

result1 = bst_model.predict(xgb.DMatrix(df))
print(np.around(result1[0], decimals=2))
```

output:

> [0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00]

**Predict right, create dmatrix from numpy array:**

```
np_arr = np.zeros(shape=(1, 680))
np_arr[0] = data_list

result2 = bst_model.predict(xgb.DMatrix(np_arr))
print(np.around(result2[0], decimals=2))
```

output:

> [0.03 0.20 0.00 0.00 0.09 0.58 0.02 0.02 0.08]

As the outputs show, the predicts are totally different, what's wrong with my code? Anyone who can help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked whether `xgb.DMatrix(df)` and `xgb.DMatrix(np_arr)` result in the same matrix?

Comment: yes, you are right, I check the column order and find the column order is different between `xgb.DMatrix(df)` and `xgb.DMatrix(np_arr)`. I got the right result after the the column order adjusted.